# Can't assigned Latlng from Bundle

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2, android-bundle

[I run the debugger and get these details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrS6Q.png)

If the bundle has the Latlng, then why I can't assign it to the global variable?

This is InputTempatActivity class where I get the Latlng:

```
private Agenda agenda;
private Intent intent, intent2;
private Bundle args, args2;
private List<Address> addresses;
private LatLng latLng;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input_tempat);

    intent = getIntent();
    args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE"); \\This is from MapsActivity
    addresses = (List<Address>) args.getSerializable("DetailLokasi");
    latLng = new LatLng(addresses.get(0).getLatitude(), addresses.get(0).getLongitude());

    intent2 = new Intent(InputTempatActivity.this, InputKegiatanActivity.class);
    args2 = new Bundle();

    agenda = new Agenda();

    args2.putSerializable("Agenda", agenda);
    args2.putParcelable("Latlng", latLng);
    intent2.putExtra("BUNDLE", args2);
    startActivity(intent2);
}
```

And this is where I get the problem--at InputKegiatanActivity:

```
private Intent intent;
private Bundle args;
private LatLng latLng;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input_kegiatan);

    intent = getIntent();
    args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
    getAgenda = (Agenda) args.getSerializable("Agenda");
    latLng = args.getParcelable("Latlng");
}
```

I've tried `latLng = (Latlng) args.getParcelable("Latlng")` but it's pointless. How do i solve this?

Comment: Are you using the same package for `LatLng` object? Could you show the import statements?

Comment: I use `android.location.Address` for InputTempatActivity (since i get the latlng through this class) and `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng` for InputKegiatanActivity. Both in the same package.